# What causes sometimes low voltage & sometimes high voltage on different circuits in my house? And I have to run 2 space heaters for either to work

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral, low-voltage, voltage

I’ve had issues with flickering lights for a while & over the summer we added a window unit to my sons room & you could barely tell it was running. I used my meter to check several outlets since the issue is not in just one room & I’ve found fluxing voltage between 95v-148v. The winter is now here & when I turn on a space heater the elements are very dim & the fan barely runs but if I turn on a second space heater plugged into the same circuit they both work but neither will work correctly alone & it’s almost like the more load I place on the circuit the higher the voltage goes

Comment: It sounds like a loss neutral that causes you to use both halves of the panel to make stuff work.   Will probably need to have your power company come out to check their wires/connections, but sometimes it is on your side of the meter.  It can be dangerous so something to be checked now(yesterday better), than to wait.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I’ve checked several outlets with my meter In different rooms & they are all split either 95v or 140+v but I’m not seeing voltage on the neutral or ground. Hopefully this is on the PC side

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like a failing neutral wire somewhere in the supply to your house.  If it fails completely, the voltages on any 120V sockets could vary wildly between 0V and 240V.
Get it fixed before it starts destroying appliances, or it overheats and starts a fire.

Comment: Yeah, OP needs to call their electric utility on their outage number ASAP

Comment: where is Harper - Reinstate Neutral when you need them?